# Why is onCharacteristicChanged never called when it should be?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I'm working with Bluetooth (BLE) in an Android app.

There is a characteristic that should be triggering callbacks to onCharacteristicChanged, but the callbacks never happen. Other functions of the device which don't rely on these callbacks work fine. I did setCharacteristicNotification(true) for the characteristic.

I've tried issuing readCharacteristic to explicity read it, but that doesn't do anything.

I know the device works because I have an iOS app that uses the same device and it receives these callbacks fine. I also have access to a debug log on the device itself and I can see that it is trying to send the data I'm expecting.

Does anyone know what would cause Android to fail to call onCharacteristicChanged even though notifications are set? I read somewhere that there is a limit of 15 active notifications, but I only have one so that can't be it.

Thanks.

Comment: I have not worked on this particular API, so not sure what could be the exact issue. Here's something that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088818/ble-gatt-oncharacteristicchanged-not-called-after-subscribing-to-notification

Comment: Hey, can you update the question with the signature of the `onCharacteristicChanged` function you are using?

Comment: Also, in this context, it would be useful to know what version of Android you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting characteristic callback is not enough. You need to write a proper descriptor value to activate notifications. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39492068

Comment: Yes, I came across this a couple of hours ago and it solved the problem. I've never had to do anything like this in my iOS apps so I wasn't expecting it. Thanks.